# Add read-only access to arbitrary path to a flatpak app with overrides

Tags: flatpak

I have installed [`org.apache.netbeans`](https://github.com/flathub/org.apache.netbeans) with flatpak. Now, I want the app to have read-only access to `/usr/local/bin`. So it can run some binaries like `lessc` installed via `npm`.

In [flatpak's docs](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions-reference.html#filesystem-permissions) it is explained that permission options may be added to the overrides.

> The following permission options can also be added:
>
> - `:ro` - read-only access
> - `:rw` - read/write access (this is the default)
> - `:create` - read/write access, and create the directory if it doesn’t exist

So I tried this command:

```
sudo flatpak override --filesystems=/usr/local/bin:ro org.apache.netbeans
```

But I get this error:

> error: Unknown option --filesystems=/usr/local/bin

How do I add the *read-only* option to the permission?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this was a stupid fail! the option should have been added with `--filesystem` - without the 's' at the end.

The correct command is:

```
sudo flatpak override --filesystem=/usr/local/bin:ro org.apache.netbeans
```

This command works and the result can be verified by running `sudo flatpak info --show-permissions org.apache.netbeans`.

**Disclaimer**
In Netbeans I still was not able to access the path, but that's the case because the `/usr` dir already exist in the sandbox. And is mounted in `/var/run/host/usr`.